# Solr Queries do not return expected values

Tags: search, solr

We have a solr configuration simply like this https://gist.github.com/118d17e93267123f4870

According to that, I'm indexing a title **The Secret of Rhonda Byrne or the Law of Attraction in the Bible** with an id.

Then I go to the Solr Analysis tool to see how its gonna get indexed in this field. So the index analysis if that field type with given value is returning something like;

```
secret rhonda byrne law attraction bible
```

Just to make sure, I'm querying the id field of that title to see if its there. Positive.

But when I query this index with the analysis tool result I get no results. My query is like;

```
select?qf=title_stm&q="Secret+Rhonda+Byrne+Law+Attraction+Bible"&fl=id,title&defType=dismax
```

As given in comments, debug output of that query is here;
https://gist.github.com/9b88fd6b5f043c90d539

Comment: how does you debug query look like ? can you add debugQuery=on in the url for the query that is generated.

Comment: here it is. https://gist.github.com/9b88fd6b5f043c90d539

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is with : -

```
<filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
        ignoreCase="true"
        words="stopwords.txt"
        enablePositionIncrements="true"
        />
```

The enablePositionIncrements with increment the positions whenever it encounters the stopwords.
Hence, when you do an exact phrase match this would not match as position of the indexed title are not next to each other.

Read more of it [here](http://lucidworks.lucidimagination.com/display/lweug/Suppressing+Stop+Word+Indexing).

You should disable the position increments to able to be do a phrase match.

```
<filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
        ignoreCase="true"
        words="stopwords.txt"
        enablePositionIncrements="false"
        />
```